# bluetooth low volume on auto connection, ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth

The problem is:

I was using my bluetooth earphone normally, then I put my earphone back to the phonebox, resulting in an auto shutdown of my earphone and disconnection with my laptop, while my laptop's bluetooth was still on. After I took my earphone out of box, it turned on automatically, and resulting in an auto reconnection with my laptop's bluetooth. The problem is, the volume became really low than before. I have to manually 'disconnect' and then 'connect' my earphone to make the volume normal as before.

This situation seems to happen every time my earphone 'auto' connect to my laptop. Is there any solution?